# Creating multiple SQL tables that have the same initial values but different table names when the query executes

Tags: php, ios, mysql, json

I am developing an iOS application that allows users to create a party playlist and have other users join that party playlist to vote on the songs in the playlist.

I am using SQL (connecting to iOS through php) to execute a "create table" query when the party is created. This table will have song names, artist names, song URLS (needed to play song), and vote count for each song.

My problem is I am stuck understanding how you would create a table for each party created by a user of the application. If you have a `create table party(...)` query and execute it more than once, it will say `table 'party' already exists`.

Is there any way to have a single query that will make each individual party table name distinct from one another? Kind of like party1 table, party2 table, party3 table...

Comment: I wouldn't create a table per party. I would have a single table and add a 'partyid' column and use that in your queries against the tables

Comment: I totally agree with @Paulw11. Files are more appropriate to do that...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion each playlist, should not be put as a table. All playlist needs to be put into a table and its songs need to be put into another table. See below

table playlists

```
    id | user_id 
party1 |   userA
party2 |   userA
pop1   |   userB
```

table playlist_songs

```
id | playlist_id | song_name | artist_name|                    song_urls
 1 |   party1    | My Song A |       Mr Me| http://www.me.com/song_a.mp3
 2 |   party2    | My Song B |       Mr Me| http://www.me.com/song_a.mp3
 3 |   party1    | My Song C |       Mr Me| http://www.me.com/song_a.mp3
 4 |   pop1      | My Music 1|      Ms You| http://www.you.com/1.mp3
```

As you can see, this way you don't need to worry about creating tables for each playlist.

Let's see
userA has 2 playlist (one has a song and the other one has 2 songs)
userB has 1 playlist with one song

-- BELOW IS NOT RECOMMENDED --

However if you insists on creating tables, you can always inject an IOS variable into the create table SQL that you use

so instead of

```
var sql = "CREATE TABLE PARTY'
```

you use

```
var sql  = "CREATE TABLE PARTY" + variable
```

where variable can be a date timestamp

Hope it helps

Comment: I'm going to give this a try. Thank you!